# convert index to period and back to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a function that takes a dataframe with datetimeindex, converts the index to period, does something, and then converts the dataframe back to timestamp.

I want to make sure that the returned index does not change when I convert to period and then back to timestamp.

This is what I have so far:

```
def generate_df(freq):
    dates = pd.date_range("2023-01-01", periods=10, freq=freq)
    return pd.DataFrame({'values': range(10)}, index=dates)

def func(df, freq):
    df_period = df.to_period(freq=freq)
    # do something to df_period
    df_timestamp = df_period.to_timestamp(freq=freq)
    # check that index is the same
    assert df.index.equals(df_timestamp.index), "index is not the same"


df = generate_df('D')
func(df,'D') # works

df = generate_df('M')
func(df, 'M') # works

df = generate_df('MS')
func(df, 'MS') # does not work
```

There are freq parameters that do not work for to_period. For example: 'MS', 'BQ'.

Is there a way to get the list of supported offset aliases that do not work with to_period? Any suggestions for a workaround for those aliases?

Edit:
I followed the recommendations in the links shared in the comments.
dates = pd.date_range("2023-01-01", periods=10, freq='W')
t_dates = dates.to_period().to_timestamp()

It works for the most part but at least for freq='W' it does not work.

Comment: Duplicate index to new column and do whatever you wish with it? Do you really need the periods as index?

Comment: That wouldn’t work. I’m using a third party library that needs period. I simplified the example but in reality I don’t even get the same indices back. I have preserve the frequency of the original dataframe once I get the new one with periods.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38914

Comment: And this may contain the list that you're looking for: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13871.